# Javascript use reserved keyword as key

Tags: javascript

Doing so

```
var x = new Array();
x['length']=5;
```

will make x an array of 5 undefined items, but I actually want to have the value '5' stored at key 'length'.

Is that possible?

Comment: I have to parse a file containing many words and store the number of occurences of each word.

Comment: Use an object instead, like so:  var x = new Object (); x["length"] = 5; x["another_key"] = 10; and so on.  So iterate through the list, you can do:  for (var a in x) {...}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript arrays do not have keys. You are looking for objects:

```
var x = {}
x.length = 5;
```

Comment: Side note: As an array is an object, it actually *has* keys, but the `length` key is already used for a property.

Comment: Very important distinction. Thank you. What I should have written is "are not meant to be used for key/value pairs"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this you'd be better off creating an object rather than an array. This should give you what you want.

```
var x = {};
x['length'] = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to parse a file containing many words and store the number of occurences of each word

Use an object, and make the words the keys. You aren't storing sequential / ordered data, so you shouldn't use an array.

```
var word_count = {};
for (var i; i < words.length; i++) {
  var word = words[i];
  if (word_count[word]) {
    word_count[word]++;
  } else {
    word_count[word] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use objects instead of arrays to store your data. But if you need to use Arrays (you might need to use their functionality), You could cripple the words and store them as array keys.

Use some kind of simple rule to follow to bypass all the possible keywords. For example prefix all your array keys with a "_" character. This way you could always restore the original words from the keys, by simply removing their first character, and you are sure you are not referencing any specific property of the Array objects (like the length property).

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods on a javascript object using two different syntaxes. The familiar 'dot' syntax with parens to invoke the method, and the square bracket syntax. You can 'call' a method on a javascript object using the syntax `myObj["methodname"](args)`.  This is handy when you want to construct the method name dynamically using strings.  Remember, objects in javascript are very much like a hash table (dictionary) where keys denote property and function names. If a key's value holds a function, it can be invoked (using parentheses).

In your example, Array has a method called 'length'. You are inadvertently calling its setter (which sets the length of the array to empty values, i.e., undefined).

Putting that all aside, you really do want a hash (associative array) in this case. An array is an offset indexed data structure.

A simple object literal like `myObj = {}` will suffice to give you hash semantics (again, objects in javascript are already like hashes) and you can then call `myObj.whatever = "some value"`